# Dealing with plus and minus signs in regexpr in R

Tags: regex, r, string, character, numeric

I would like to include the the minus or plus sign when extracting numeric data from a character string. The number is 8.81e+001. Using the following code I can get the e, but not the + and subsequent numbers.

```
wg_co2 <- all_data[wg_co2 <- grep("Carbon Dioxide",all_data)] [3]
wg_co2 <-regmatches(wg_co2, regexpr("[0-9]{1,9}.[e-e0-9]{1,9}",wg_co2))
wg_co2
```

Any tips gratefully received!

JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[0-9]{1,9}.[[e-e0-9]-]{1,9}[+-][0-9]+
```

This should do it for you